# Exclude specific file in Gradle protobuf plugin

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle to build my project and compile some protocol buffers using the Gradle Protobuf Plugin.  I'd like to build the protos in several directories and exclude a single file.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/java',
                    'generated/main/java'
            ]
        }
        proto {
            srcDirs = [
              'foo/proto',
              '../bar/proto'
            ]
            exclude '../bar/proto/names.proto'
        }
    } }
```

However the `exclude` statement does not work and `names.proto` is still included in the protoc invocation, any ideas?